# How to select a sub-query with MySQL using the WHERE part?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which look like:

The `money` table looks like the following:

```
id  type     cash
1   54       3.23
2   293      1.12
3   181      4.00
```

The `plus` table looks like the following:

```
id   money_id bonus
1    3         0.50
2    2         0.10
```

What I basically want is to select ALL data from the `money` table, including `money.cash` with the added bonus from the `plus` table, if they have any, and I want to select only those records, which have more than 1.50 cash (including the bonus).

So the result I'd like to achieve is:

```
id  type     cash_full
1   54            3.23
2   181           4.50
```

I have tried to make some query, but it always says error, when I want to include the `cash_full` into the WHERE statement. Other than that, it's working flawlessly, I just can't filter the query with the `cash_full` column.

```
SELECT mo.*,
IFNULL
(
    mo.cash + 
    (
    SELECT bonus 
    FROM plus as pu 
    WHERE mo.id = pu.money_id
    ), mo.cash
) as cash_full
FROM `money` as mo 
WHERE cash_full >= 1.5
```

So how is it possible that this query is not working? Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: You can use joins instead of subquery.

Comment: While there are numerous solutions below that will give you the results (and probably quicker), the issue with your SQL is that you have a WHERE clause that checks the value of a column alias. When the WHERE is processed that alias name is not yet in existence. You could duplicate the code into the WHERE clause to get the value, or you could just change the WHERE to a HAVING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. Assuming you can have more than one bonus per money id :*

You can use an alias in an having clause (with mysql), after having grouped the values from money table

```
select mo.id, mo.type,  mo.cash + sum(coalesce(p.bonus, 0)) as cash_full
from money mo
left join plus p on p.money_id = mo.id
group by mo.id, mo.type, mo.cash
having cash_full > 1.5
```

with other db, you would have to use a subquery, or repeat the "aliased" operation in the having clause : something like

```
having mo.cash +  sum(coalesce(p.bonus, 0)) > 1.5
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae73c/5)

*2. Assuming you can't have more than one bonus per money id*

You can do a subquery to avoid repeating the "addition"*

```
select id, type, cash_full
from (
   select mo.id, mo.type, mo.cash + coalesce(p.bonus, 0) as cash_full
   from money mo
   left join plus p on p.money_id = mo.id) s
where cash_full > 1.5;
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. It is working flawlessly now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple LEFT JOIN will do it:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, a.cash + IFNULL(SUM(b.bonus), 0) AS cash_bonus
FROM money a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN plus b
ON a.id = b.money_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.type
HAVING cash_bonus > 1.50
```

Note that this is a bit strange as it has a non aggregate field that isn't in the GROUP BY clause. This should be fine in MySQL but might cause issues in other flavours of SQL. In which case a LEFT JOIN to a sub query might be necessary:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, a.cash + IFNULL(b.tot_bonus, 0) AS cash_bonus
FROM money a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT money_id, SUM(bonus) AS tot_bonus
    FROM plus 
    GROUP BY money_id
) b
ON a.id = b.money_id
WHERE a.cash + IFNULL(b.tot_bonus, 0) > 1.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select mo.*,sum(mo.cash+ IFNULL(pl.cash_full,0)) as cash_full from money mo
LEFT JOIN plus pl on pl.money_id=mo.id and pl.cash_full >=1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

```
select m.id, m.type, (m.cash + p.bonus) as cash_full from money m, plus p WHERE m.id=p.money_id;
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae5e0be/5) to have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mo.*, (mo.cash + IFNULL(p.bonus,0)) AS cash_full
FROM `money` as mo 
LEFT JOIN `plus` AS p
ON p.money_id = mo.id
WHERE cash_full >= 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select m.*, (IFNULL(p.bonus,0)+ m.cash) as cash_full
from money m left join plus p
on m.id = p.id
and cash_full >= 1.50
```

If you are using SQL Server/MS Access use ISNULL, Oracle use NVL, My SQL use IFNULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  M.ID, 
  M.TYPE, 
  M.CASH, 
  IFNULL(P.BONUS, 0) AS BONUS, 
  M.CASH + IFNULL(P.BONUS, 0) AS TOTAL   
FROM
  MONEY M
  LEFT JOIN PLUS P ON
    P.MONEY_ID = M.ID
WHERE
  M.CASH + IFNULL(P.BONUS, 0) >= 1.5
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8473/9)